# How can a tr's TD know what is the value of the upper tr's td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i will explan my problem with an example
I have this table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>First</th><th>Second</th><th>Third</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I know via Javascript that in the second position of the first and the second `<tr>` I have `B` and `E`?

I'm using the plugin Datatables and I have this table: 
[image: Click]

But when I go into responsive mode I want to have the first tr value followed by the second tr value and then the numeric value. Example:

```
WP bar: value   
WP psi: value
```

Now i have only

```
bar: value  
psi: value
```

Comment: Why are you using `[table]` instead of `<table>`?

Comment: You could do it by counting the number of elements in a row, for example - but that works only when there's no colspan, you'd have to accommodate for that. But, what do you want to do with that information exactly? That info would be important in order to find out how to approach this

Comment: @Barmar because i didn't know how to put code :P

Comment: Paste your code, select it with the mouse, and mark it as literal code by using the `{}` tool or pressing Control-k.

Comment: @BenPhilipp I made another screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/U3CP3iQ.png 
Look the other screenshot to understand what i want to do... You also should know how the plugin DataTables work (shortly, it can transform the table into a responsive-table by hiding columns and showing them into a hidden div (https://www.datatables.net/blog/2014-07-16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/9cgtky3x/
(Click toggle to switch between views)

First, we add the units to every cell in every row after the 2nd, based on the column number they're in.

Then, we add the Table Heading to every cell in rows after the 2nd, based on the column number they're in, accounting for the colspan of the TH by adding the colspan-value to the count.

Those additions are wrapped inside a span with a class which we hide in desktop view, and show in responsive view.

Documentation in the annotations.

It may not be the most elegant solution, but better than none

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colcount = 0;  // for iterating through columns (TH captions)
  var lastcol = 0;  // for iterating through columns (TH captions)
  var unicount = 0;  // for iterating through columns (Unit labels)

  // -------- Add units to cells -------- //
  $("#resme tr:eq(1) td").each(function() {  // iterate through TDs within 2nd TR
    var unit = this.innerHTML;  // get unit label
    $("#resme tr:gt(1)").each(function() {   // for all TRs after the 2nd
      $(this).find("td:eq(" + unicount + ")").each(function() {  // add unit label to the TDs within the given column
        this.innerHTML = "<span class='mob'>" + unit + ": </span>" + this.innerHTML;
      });
    })
    unicount++;
  });

  // -------- Add TH captions to cells -------- //
  $("#resme th").each(function() {  // for each TH
    var cap = this.innerHTML;  // get label
    if ($(this).attr("colspan") > 1) {  // if th spans more than one column, account for that
      colcount += 1 * $(this).attr("colspan");
    } else {  // otherwise, count one
      colcount++;
    }

    var rcount = 2;   // for iterating through TRs
    $("#resme tr:gt(1)").each(function() {  // all TRs after the 2nd
        var ob = this;
        for (k = lastcol; k < colcount; k++) {  // only within the range of the TH columns
          $(ob).find("td:eq(" + k + ")").each(function() {  // find the TDs within the given range
            $(this).html("<span class='mob'>" + cap + " </span>" + $(this).html());  // add the TH caption
          });
        }
      rcount++;
    });
    lastcol = colcount;   // So we won't add the next caption to already processed TDs
  });
});

function toggle() {
  $("#resme").toggleClass("res");
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="resme">
  <tr class="desktop">
    <th colspan="3">Hose size</th>
    <th colspan="2">ID</th>
    <th colspan="2">OD</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="desktop">
    <td>dash</td>
    <td>inch</td>
    <td>DN</td>
    <td>mm</td>
    <td>inch</td>
    <td>mm</td>
    <td>inch</td>
  </tr>
```

(values...)

```
<button onclick="toggle()">
  toggle
</button>
```

Comment: It seems ok, on monday i'll return to my work-office and i'll try your solution.. I'll have to adapt it with the DataTable plugin..

Comment: Were you successful in implementing it?